# Wordpress/Woocommerce checkout page 500 error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, braintree, http-status-code-500

Im getting 500 error page on my woocommerce store checkout page. I noticed that when cart is empty there is no error, only when I add products in it

the address is https://www.belizajec.si/webshop/checkout/

when debug mode enabled I get this error

```
Notice: register_sidebar was called incorrectly. No id was set in the arguments array for the "Translator For Header" sidebar. Defaulting to "sidebar-1". Manually set the id to "sidebar-1" to silence this notice and keep existing sidebar content. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 4.2.0.) in /home/apartkri/public_html/webshop/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4137

Fatal error: Class 'WC_Gateway_Paypal' not found in /home/apartkri/public_html/webshop/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-payment-gateways.php on line 105
```

thanks

Comment: Please enable WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php and post any error codes here.

Comment: I have updated question with error on that page. What i also noticed is that I get the same error message when I try to open Woocommerce settings page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you update to WooCommerce 3.0? Make sure the theme you are using is compatible with WooCommerce 3.0. If it's a plugin you are using for Paypal disable it first and see if thats the one causing an issue.

Seems like some incompatibility.

Comment: I still didnt updated to Woo 3, but the problem is that i cant access woo settings page too now, same error message appears. I do have "Braintree For WooCommerce Pro" plugin, but after I disable it the problem still exist

Comment: Try reuploading WooCommerce manually. Maybe a file inclusion missing? Previous version of version 2 at https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/woocommerce.2.6.14.zip. Also try disabling all other plugins by renaming wp-content/plugins/ to something like wp-content/plugins-old/. Make backups though.

Answer (score 1):

ok, the problem was solved by re-uploading all Woocommerce files over existing files on server.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the plugin / theme conflict issue and to be honest cannot be judge directly.

However, there are some primary steps which you can follow, as below :-

1. Disable all plugins except "Woocommerce"
2. Activate WordPress default theme

After this check by following same procedure.

Let me know if I can help you further...

Comment: did all of that and problem is still there

Comment: As already said it is hard to judge the issue. Can you please allow me to look further in your system to check the issue?